# How to cd into a directory with space in the name?

Tags: bash, cygwin, cd

I'm attempting to get into the directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents`:

```
$ DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents"

$ echo $DOCS
/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents

$ cd $DOCS
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Users/my\: No such file or directory

$ cd /cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents
(success)
```

When I manually type it in, the backspace does its escape character thing, but not when I use parameter expansion with the variable `DOCS`.

I tried other variations such as no backslash.

```
$ DOCS=/cygdrive/c/Users\ dir/Documents

$ echo $DOCS
/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents

$ cd $DOCS
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Users/my: No such file or directory
```

or

```
$ DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents"

$ echo $DOCS
/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents

$ cd $DOCS
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Users/my: No such file or directory
```

The same happens for `$HOME`:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/my dir
```

`cd $HOME` doesn't work either. Quotes must be put around it.

What the heck:

```
$ DOCS="\"/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents\""

$ echo $DOCS
"/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents"

$ cd $DOCS
-bash: cd: "/cygdrive/c/Users/my: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Don't escape the space, but do add the quote marks : `DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents"`

Comment: No difference. I edited above so there is no escape in the space.

Comment: No realy difference if I escape the space using a backslash or quotes, but I did it again anyway. See revision.

Comment: When you want to `cd`, use `cd "$DOCS"`

Comment: I don't want to use quotes. I'm lazy, heh. Although I'll throw in that it DOES work.

Comment: Well if you are _that_ lazy then you are out of luck.

Comment: You can solve almost any laziness problem with an alias - but I am assuming that this is happening inside a script, so I don't understand the "use quotes every time" comment (in your response to John Kugelman's answer).

Comment: Its not a script. I'm setting up an environment variable

Comment: OK - see my answer. An alias (a bit like an environment variable, but more powerful) will give you what you need with the minimum of fuss/typing. Who wants to type `cd $DOC` when they could just type `mydoc`. You could even make it a single character if you really wanted...

Comment: @Floris: If all you have is an alias that does a `cd` to a specified directory, what if you want to do an `ls -l` on that directory, as in `ls -l "$DOCS"`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: `mydoc; ls -l`. If you looks at the earlier comments you will see I had suggested a proper definition and use of `"$DOCS"` but was told "I am too lazy for that" - so I gave an alternative. Trying to work some alternatives is all...

Comment: It should be enclosed in double quotes because of the [Quote Removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal) @Floris

Comment: @user2316667 : _ I'm lazy_ : In this case, I suggest to use zsh instead of bash. Not only means invoking it to type only 3 characters instead of 4, You can also do a `cd $DOCS`, instead of `cd "$DOCS"`, because in zsh wordsplitting is done before parameter extension.

Comment: @user2316667 : For bash, another blessing for lazy users in interactive shells is to turn on `cdable_vars`, in which case even a `cd DOCS` is sufficient - no need to type a `$` or quotes. See the bash man page for the `shopt` command.

Comment: If you really find quoting annoying (like I do), consider changing from bash to zsh. The shells have some similarity, so that you will find yourself at home quickly, and zsh does word splitting before parameter expansion - so you don't need the quotes in your examples. Actually, I find zsh meanwhile more convenient than bash in virtually all respects, but this is just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
$ cd "$DOCS"
```

You need to quote `"$DOCS"` to prevent spaces from being parsed as word separators. More often than not, variable references should be quoted.

Note that `$HOME` would have the same problem. The issue is coming from when the shell evaluates variable references; it's nothing to do with what variables you use or how you assign to them. It's the expansion that needs to be quoted.

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/my dir
```

This is deceptive. `echo` is actually echoing the two strings `/home/my` and `dir`. If you use `cd` or `ls` you'll see how it's actually working.

```
$ ls $HOME
ls: cannot access /home/my: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dir: No such file or directory
$ cd $HOME
bash: cd: /home/my: No such file or directory
$ cd "$HOME"
<success!>
```

---

> Can I ask why it works when I manually type it in but not in a variable?

Great question! Let's examine the commands you typed:

```
$ DOCS="\"/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents\""
$ echo $DOCS
"/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents"
$ cd $DOCS
-bash: cd: "/cygdrive/c/Users/my: No such file or directory
```

The reason this doesn't work is because Bash doesn't parse quotes inside variable expansions. It *does* perform word splitting, so whitespace in unquoted variable expansions is taken as word separators. It *doesn't* parse quotes in any way, meaning you can't put double quotes inside a variable to override word splitting.

```
$ cd $DOCS
```

Because of this, `cd` is passed two parameters. As far as `cd` knows it looks like you wrote:

```
$ cd '"/cygdrive/c/Users/my' 'dir/Documents"'
```

Two parameters, with double quotes intact.

Comment: I don't want to use quotes every time. That is why I originally inserted the backslash.

Comment: @user2316667 Sorry. You have to.

Comment: Well... how does $HOME do it?

Comment: -_-. I can safely do cd $HOME but not cd $DOCS...?

Comment: Oh.. what the... I could've sworn I could do cd $HOME, but... hm. Okay, is there a way to include " inside the variable? I will try that now.

Comment: No; there isn't a way to include the double quotes inside the variable, short of having to use `eval cd $DOCS` which is worse than `cd "$DOCS"` (by 3 characters).  The double quotes are necessary around the variable; use them and get over the overwhelming desire for laziness.  Or don't create folders with spaces in the names — that's even easier.

Comment: Can I ask why it works when I manually type it in but not in a variable? Also view edits in op. I got double quotes inside the variable. Still same problem though. Any plausible explanation?

Comment: When you type it manually with the backslash, the shell reads it all as a word and `cd`'s to the right place, spaces and all.  When you save the name with a space in it in a variable, the shell splits `$DOCS` at the space unless you surround it with double quotes.  Even if you include one or two backslashes in the variable value, the shell splits the value at the space.  You'd have to use `eval cd $DOCS` when `$DOCS` contains a backslash-space to get the `cd` to work OK.  In a sense, it is just 'the way it works'.  It is the way it 'always has worked', too.

Comment: $DOCS "splits?" Are you saying $DOCS becomes an array when spaces are included? Nope.. I tested it. $DOCS[0] outputs the entire, proper string. And I even echoed it above. Conclusive evidence.. no?

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you very much. I appreciate your insight beyond the scope of the question!

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for providing my "I learn something new every day" moment.

Answer (score 57):

SOLUTION:

```
cd "Documents and Photos"
```

problem solved.

The reason I'm submitting this answer is you'll find that StackOverflow is being used by every day users (not just web devs, programmers or power users) and this was the number one result for a simple Windows user question on Google.

People are becoming more tech-savvy, but aren't necessarily familiar with command line in the cases above.

Answer (score 7):

To change to a directory with spaces on the name you just have to type like this:

`cd My\ Documents`

Hit **enter** and you will be good

Answer (score 5):

```
$ DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents"
```

Here's your first problem. This puts an actual backslash character into `$DOCS`, as you can see by running this command:

```
$ echo "$DOCS"
/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ `
```

When defining `DOCS`, you do need to escape the space character. You can quote the string (using either single or double quotes) *or* you can escape just the space character with a backslash. You can't do both. (On most Unix-like systems, you can have a backslash in a file or directory name, though it's not a good idea. On Cygwin or Windows, `\` is a directory delimiter. But I'm going to assume the actual name of the directory is `my dir`, not `my\ dir`.)

```
$ cd $DOCS
```

This passes two arguments to `cd`. The first is `cygdrive/c/Users/my\`, and the second is `dir/Documents`. It happens that `cd` quietly ignores all but its first argument, which explains the error message:

```
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Users/my\: No such file or directory
```

To set `$DOCS` to the name of your `Documents` directory, do any one of these:

```
$ DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents"
$ DOCS='/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents'
$ DOCS=/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents
```

Once you've done that, to change to your `Documents` directory, enclose the variable reference in double quotes (that's a good idea for *any* variable reference in bash, unless you're sure the value doesn't have any funny characters):

```
$ cd "$DOCS"
```

You might also consider giving that directory a name without any spaces in it -- though that can be hard to do in general on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Use quotes!
`cd "Name of Directory"`

Or you can go to the file explorer and click "copy path" in the top left corner!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to CD into a path where the directory with space comes in between. You can wrapped the entire path into quotes.

```
cd "C:\Users\JOE\Local Sites\skeleton"
```

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin has issue recognizing space in between the PC name. So to solve this, you have to use "\" after the first word then include the space, then the last name.

such as ".../my\ dir/"

```
$ cd /cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents
```

Another interesting and simple way to do it, is to put the directory in quotation marks ("")

e.g 
run it as follows:

```
$ cd c:
$ cd Users
$ cd "my dir"
$ cd Documents
```

Hope it works?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents";

cd "$DOCS"
```

Comment: Did *you* try it? That puts an actual backslash character into `"$DOCS"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the following in your `.cshrc` (or `.bashrc`, or whatever your default shell is):

```
alias mydoc 'cd "/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents"'
```

First time you do this, you have to do

```
source .cshrc
```

to update the shell with this new alias, then you can type

```
mydoc
```

anytime you want to `cd` to your directory.

Laziness is the mother of invention...

Comment: I think they said that about war... I'll try it. Gotta install alias though (cygwin).

Comment: Ugh, needed new setup.exe. 2 more seconds.

Comment: Works! But now I'm mad because cd $DOCS should for all purposes have worked... Could you explain why the variable didn't work when manually typing in (what the variable SHOULD Have been expanded to) did? If anything trumps my laziness, it is curiosity.

Comment: I see that @JohnKugelman already answered your other question... "it can't be done"; I think this means that my method is the most promising way to achieve what you actually wanted - to change to this directory with the least amount of typing (and without using quotes).

Comment: That gives you a way to `cd` into the directory, but not to do anything else with it. If `$DOCS` is properly defined, you can do things like `ls -l "$DOCS"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move from `c:\` and you want to go to `c:\Documents and settings`, write on console: `c:\Documents\[space]+tab` and cygwin will autocomplete it as `c:\Documents\ and\ settings/`

Answer (score 1):

Use the backslash symbol (`\`) to escape the space:

```
C:\> cd my folder
```

will be

```
 C:\> cd my\ folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use quotes around the file that has a space in it

```
cd "file with space"
```

Comment: This answer has already been given by others, like Mindsect Team.

Answer (score 0):

ok i spent some frustrating time with this problem too. My little guide.

Open desktop for example. If you didnt switch your disc in cmd, type:

**cd desktop**

Now if you want to display subfolders:

**cd**, make 1 **spacebar**, and press **tab** 2 times

Now if you want to enter directory/file with ***SPACE IN NAME***. Lets open some **file name** f.g., to open it we need to type:

**cd file\ name**

p.s. notice this space after slash :)

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD1**: With Quotes

> `cd "C:/Prgram Files (x86)"`
>
> `cd 'C:/Program Files (x86)'`
>
> **Generalised**
>
> `cd 'Folder Path'`

**Method2**: Without using Quotes

> `cd Program\ Files \(x86\)`
>
> **Generalised**
> Whenever we want to skip next character we use blackslash `\`.

For the above question:
`cd /cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using quotes, for a directory you want to go to often, you could use the [`cdable_vars` shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin):

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
docs='/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents'
```

Now, to change into that directory from anywhere, you can use

```
cd docs
```

and the shell will indicate which directory it changed to:

```
$ cd docs
/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

The approaches discussed here don't work for aliases in a consistent basis - adding/not adding quotes etc.

E.g. if I have a directory variable like `dir_with_spaces='path of the directory with spaces'`, it is not possible to directly use `alias new_dir='cd $dir_with_spaces/subdirectory'.`

As an alternative, it would be useful to create a custom function that adds quotes around the cd, and then use this custom function instead.

```
cdwq() # Custom cd to support directories with spaces in the name by adding quotes around it
{
 local folder_path=$1
 cd "${folder_path}"
}
```

Now, it is possible to use this custom function with any directory variable.

```
dir_with_spaces='path of the directory with spaces'
dir_without_spaces='path_of_the_directory_without_spaces'

alias new_dir1='cdwq $dir_with_spaces/subdirectory1'
alias new_dir2='cdwq $dir_with_spaces/subdirectory2'
alias new_dir3='cdwq $dir_without_spaces/subdirectory3'
alias new_dir4='cdwq $dir_without_spaces/subdirectory4'
alias new_dir5='cdwq $dir_with_spaces/subdirectory5'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is space inside dir name, you can use wild card character (`?` or `*`) in place of space & wrap the directory name in double-quotes.

Example - in the below path, "Program Files" has space inside -

```
/mnt/c/Program Files$ JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/"Program?Files"/Java/jdk-11.0.12

/mnt/c/Program Files$ cd $JAVA_HOME

/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.12$
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is too simple

```
cd 'my app'
```

Or you can double-quote

```
cd "my app"
```

Both commands should work in most **Unix-like** terminals, including **Linux** and **macOS**.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents"
```

Try:

```
DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my dir/Documents"
```

This should work on any [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) system.

Comment: I should throw in, I'm using Cygwin. Shouldn't make a difference but I tried that and didn't work.

Comment: What does the ls /cygdrive/c/Users show? Whatever Cygwin sees the directory as should be used as the BASH variable. <br>
Cygwin is often less than perfect about windows-unicey file translation. If you're not porting software, and don't require POSIX compliance, there is MinGW/MSYS which is 10-100% faster than Cygwin, and far less error prone: http://mingw.org/wiki/msys

Comment: You could also try setting the DOCS variable in the Windows User or System settings, as they are imported by default. System-> Advanced ->  Environment Variables
Cygwin is incredibly "quarky" about spaces, case sensitivity and other things, often requiring additional configuration to behave in a Unicey manner.

Comment: This can also be set at runtime via editing startcyg.bat and adding set DOCS="/cygdrive/c/Users/my\ dir/Documents"